# Strange error after upgrading JDK 8 to Amazon Corretto 11 on Windows Server 2007

Tags: java, windows, corretto

Not sure what this error is all about, but after moving away from the subscription-based Oracle JDK to Amazon Corretto JDK 11 (tried Corretto JDK 8 also), and starting Java at the command line, I get the error below:

```
The procedure entry point K32GetModuleFileNameExA could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll
```

Tried to research, but cannot find a solution. My fear is that this is an issue with this old Windows Server (2007) software.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks in advance to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 2007 is not a supported platform:

https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/faqs/

> Windows builds are supported on versions 7, 8, 10, Server 2008 R2,
> Server 2012, Server 2016 and Server 2019.

Comment: Thank you very much! I should have RTFM! My bad. In any case, you gave me the perfect answer and I thank you very much for that. All the best.